# Extract attachements using mailbox python?

Tags: python, email

I wanted to extract email attachments from mbox using mailbox library in python.

I've used following code to extract From, To, Subject, Date, Body

```
import mailbox    
mbox = mailbox.mbox('/tmp/Personal Folders/Inbox/mbox')
for message in mbox:
    print message['subject']
    print message['To']
    print message['From']
    print message['Date']
```

How to find and extract attachments in every mails? Do I need to include any more library ?

Answer (score 7):

The following python function extracts find and extracts attachment in native format :) don't forget to include

> import mailbox

```
def extractattachements(message):
    if message.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        for part in message.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue
            filename = part.get_filename()
            print filename
            fb = open(filename,'wb')
            fb.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fb.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`get_payload()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload) method .

> Return the current payload, which will be a list of [`Message`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message) objects
> when [`is_multipart()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.is_multipart) is True, or a string when [`is_multipart()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.is_multipart) is False.

Ex:

```
print message.get_payload()
```

Comment: I've already used is_multipart() to print message body if it get_content_type returns text/plain.

Comment: Right -- if the message has an attachment, then `is_multipart()` will return True, and you can then return the attachments, something like `print message.get_payload()[1:]`

Comment: I've used `message.get_payload()[1:]` and STDOUT was `[]`

Comment: I got one file like this Content-Type: text/plain; name="wave.csv.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wave.csv.txt"